# accuracy of contact sensor?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi every body :)

why when I put a link of a model on the ground, its contact sensor indicates that the link don't touch the ground ?

like this graph shows, 1 if link touches the ground, -1 else

the link doesn't move and stay in place. Normally the data of the sensor should be always 1 !

Is this a bug ? If not this means that the if link is not heavy it doesn't touch 100% the ground.I tried to make the link heavier (100 Kg), same problem.

[image: image description]

---

**EDIT**

Here is the source code :

[controller.cc](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/1431538023805714.cc)

[controller.hh](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/14315380447147794.hh)

[world.world](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/14315382132390441.world)

[CMakeLists.h](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/14315382261692165.h) (change the extension to .txt)

[cmd.h](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/14315383157617581.h) (if you want to plot with gnuplot)

the model is in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQlso5ASeC0&feature=youtu.be). the box is fixed to the ground

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8681/accuracy-of-contact-sensor-?/) by [djou07](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/969/djou07/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 78 on 2015-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I resolved the problem by changing the update rate.

First I didn't precise it. By default the frequency is 1000 times per second. So I modified it to 100 and then to 30. And it worked. Still don't understand why it loses accuracy with big frequency...

So, I want to know what is the recommended frequency ?

thanks in advance

---

Originally posted by [djou07](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/969/djou07/) with karma: 78 on 2015-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0